# Convert Json String to JsonObject Object

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
     "insertId":"qxdo1se4pjcw",
     "logName":"projects,
      "protoPayload":{
          "type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
          "authenticationInfo":{
             "principalEmail":"gserviceaccount.com"
          },
          "authorizationInfo":[
             {
                "granted":true,
                "permission":"bigquery.tables.updateData",
                "resource":"metrics_event",
                "resourceAttributes":{
                   
                }
             }
          ]
    }
```

I want to convert this to JSON object so later we can easily refer to each object
My code:

```
 String msg = message.getData().toStringUtf8();
 JsonParser pa = new JsonParser();
 JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) pa.parse(msg);
```

I can access the element using get method but how to access the element which are nested for example

`obj.get("protoPayload"`) is working fine but how to access `type`

similar to `obj.get("protoPayload").get("type")`

Answer (score 0):

Use plain JSON from org.json

`JSONObject json=new JSONObject(String source);`

This would convert valid JSON string to JSON Object.

If you want to access nested object within JSON and you already know the "key",then you can use the following.

JSONObject extends a HashMap, so you can simply use it as a HashMap:

```
JSONObject jsonChildObject = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("protoPayload");
for (Map.Entry in jsonChildOBject.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `obj.getJsonObject("protoPayload").get("type")`